# What is main difference between Content Asset and Content Slot in demandware / SFCC?

Tags: e-commerce, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

What is main difference between Content Asset and Content Slot in demandware / SFCC ?

Answer (score 9):

The main difference is because **assets** are related to *static content*, but **slots** to *marketing purposes* and they could be dynamic.

**Content Asset** is a part of HTML which is created in Business Manager and it is related to the static content of a web store. They are used for footers, headers, sidebars and all other content, which are not related to promotions. You can add to the page with this ISML tag `<iscontentasset aid="some-asset"/>`, where aid is an ID of the asset.

**Content Slot** is related to campaigns and promotions. They are not created in the Business Manager, but BM scans all `isslot` tags from ISML code and you can configure them depending on promotion, campaign, etc. HTML for content slot could be defined in ISML file or BM, depending on context of a slot. Context could be global, folder and category.

Comment: Content Slots have the ability to schedule slot content by customer group, source code, or time and day. Content slots are _managed_ within Business Manager, but defined within template code. Content Slots can be configured to show a Content Asset and therefore content assets could be used for dynamic marketing capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Both are responsible to manage/show content on storefront and both are available with support of multi locale content but Main difference between Content Slot and Content Asset is this -

In Content Slot you can set an time to show content and configure a start and end time to show content on storefront. where as in content asset you can not do this,in content asset your content is available always if content asset enable flag sets to true.

another difference is you can have a template to display product / recommendation in content slot, where as in content asset you have to put the complete HTML in the body section of content asset.

Answer (score 1):

From a business manager perspective a content asset is a piece of html displayed on the site. A content asset is either statically displayed ie footer or category etc or dynamically displayed based on campaigns ie summersale. The latter requires configuration which is performed by creating a content slot.

The developer defines which areas of the site contain content assets or content slots by adding the iscontentasset-tag and isslot-tag respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Content Asset**
Salesforce B2C Commerce supports a wide variety of content assets, including HTML text, graphics, and video. You use content assets to provide your customers non-product related information such as customer support pages, special sales, size charts, and gardening tips

**Content slot**
A content slot can be embedded in any part of your storefront site, to show products, categories, content assets, or static HTML based on a schedule. A content asset can be a flash graphic, product carousel, product search result set, or marketing graphic. You can use Business Manager to create and schedule a slot configuration, instead of changing storefront code.

Answer (score -1):

**content asset** - not to be specific restriction;
**Content slot** - An additional restriction can be applied like duration, specific locales conditions etc

Comment: Could you please translate the answer into English?